# Can I use shoulda with mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mongoid, minitest, shoulda

I want to use shoulda with mongoid, but I am getting this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord
```

I am using mongoid, though. Is it possible to use shoulda with MiniTest and mongoid? Here's my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0.beta1', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest version of shoulda-matchers. We are working to fix it, but in the meantime, please use version 2.5.0.

Comment: Still getting this error on validate_uniqueness_of using shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)

Comment: Please file a bug on http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues.